# Getting the right ATI Drivers for 6370m

Tags: 11.10, drivers, ati, lenovo

Just bought a Lenovo G570 with a Radeon 6370m video card. Tried both drivers recommended under "additional drivers".

The first driver failed.

```
Sorry, installation of this driver failed. Please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log
```

The second driver installed, but when I restarted and went to log in again, my only options were ubuntu and ubuntu 2d. No unity. There were no panels or anything, just a menu that looks like this:

```
File Edit View Go Bookmarks Help
```

So... I opened firefox and went to ATI's page to get their [latest supported driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) for my card. I uninstalled the old driver, restarted and ran the installation script.

```
sudo chmod +x ati-some-really-long-driver-name.run
./ati-some-really-long-driver-name.run
```

It said it was successful, but when I restarted - still, no unity, no application dock on the left hand side of the screen, no panels. Just the menu I described above.

What gives?

Comment: Found this pretty in-depth wiki. Will try it out tomorrow morning and see how it goes...

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29

Comment: Question: What is wrong with not having the propriety drivers? Does  it just lack 3D support and the card sits idle or what?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)