# Safe to switch to AMD in 2020?

Tags: amd-processor

I have been a Linux user since 2001. So my animosity towards AMD goes back to a decade ago :). Since then, I have been a loyal Intel user for all my Ubuntu machines.

Now, the younger guys are telling me that AMD has changed in the past years and that it is safe to switch to AMD-based hardware.

I am planning to purchase a new Ubuntu machine and I am not sure if AMD is a safe and headache-less option for an Ubuntu user nowadays.

Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: This was a interesting post!  Following this one;  I am (and; I do think very many here) are Intel Users. (Not all of them, but many I do think)  I've been thinking of  switching to AMD too, from Intel. :)  //Thanks for asking a question that I also wanted to get answers too! (I was too shy to ask XD)

Comment: I am sure there are many old-school Linux users that are interested in this as well. What is "odd" is that Linux also switched to AMD, but its top CPU indeed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the systems I'm using is an Acer aspire laptop with an AMD processor and an AMD/ATI graphics adapter. I have installed **Xubuntu 20.04.1** on the internal HD and **Kubuntu 20.04.1** on an external USB drive.

Both flavors work just fine out of the box and no proprietary drivers are needed.

Answer (score 0):

AMD is a safe and headache-less option for Ubuntu users nowadays. As far as Ubuntu support is concerned it makes no difference whatsoever whether an AMD or an Intel CPU is installed in your computer<sup>[1](https://askubuntu.com/a/89010/)</sup>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this your opinion or you have a direct experience being an AMD user as well?

Comment: I checked the link you mentioned. It was a small link so I did not detect it when I was writing a comment above. You basically linked what I have already known :) and why Intel was my first choice in the past ie because of the motherboard and graphics card. And, tell me I am wrong, but if I switch to AMD, it's not only CPU or RAM, it's the whole components switch including motherboard and graphic cards.

Comment: @ubuntico All of it is based on personal experience with a Ryzen CPU computer which was purchased in 2020. You can mix and match Ryzen series processors freely with RAM and graphics cards that are compatible with your motherboard and of course the CPU socket on the motherboard must be compatible with your choice of CPU whether it is AMD or Intel.